# Fixing / Unfixing Div when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically i have 4 divs (a Banner, left content, right content, and a footer). The banner and left content divs are fixed while the right content and footer are not. What I'd like to have happen is when the top of the footer meets the bottom of the left content div have it unfix itself and scroll together with the right div.

I setup a preview of what i currently have in jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/sgcer/270/

```
<div id="banner">BANNER</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">LEFT</div>
    <div id="right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>

#banner {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #00ff00;
    position: fixed;
}
#content {
    height: auto;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
    height: 750px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ok, but the JS part is totally empty. I understand you want us to do it for you, but it would really help us to see what you're doing wrong - guide you - suggest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YK72r/2/

What I did is called an `if` on every scroll event, used a bit of metrics math to find the height needed, changed the css of the left sidebar using jQuery's `css` method, and then added an `else` statement to revert it when scrolling back up.

```
var scrollHeight;

$(window).ready(function() {
    scrollHeight = $('#footer').offset().top - $('#left').height() - $('#left').offset().top;
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >= scrollHeight) {
        $('#left').css({
            'position': 'relative',
            'margin-top': '350px'
        });
    } else {
        $('#left').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
            'margin-top': '100px'
        });
    }
});
```

Note that I changed the heights a bit, so mind the css pixel values.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some general steps to do this:

1. Use Javascript to get the pixel positions of the `div` and footer
2. Using the `onscroll` listener, listen for when the footer should "unfix"
3. When that happens, use `className` to add a class `"fixed"` to the footer

In your CSS, you should add:

```
.fixed { position: fixed; }
```

Using jQuery would make all of this easier, too.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I would rather use a bit of "height-math" and the document `scrollTop`

Comment: +1 anyway for the way you answered the question (you did not kill all the fun)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var ftop = $("#footer").position().top;
        var lbottom = $("#footer").position().top + $("#left").height();

        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var diff = ftop - scrollTop;

        if( diff <= lbottom)
        $("#left").css("position","static");
        else
        $("#left").css("position","fixed");
    });
```