# (div scroll follow) when div meets anothere div, (div scroll follow) also scroll toggether with othere div

Tags: jquery

I have 4 divs (a header, left and right content, and a footer). i have `right content` scroll follow, What I'd like to have happen is when the top of the footer meets the bottom of the `right`, right also scroll together with the left `div`.

I setup a preview of what i currently have in [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/wFDYV/3/).

Comment: Try look at this.. seems the same with your problem..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215660/fixing-unfixing-div-when-scrolling

Comment: thank's for the reply i will review if we have same situation.

Comment: i think we are not in same situation or maybe i am wrong by the way thank's for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.min()` and a pre-calculated value to cap the right sidebar's marginTop setting, such that it won't animate beyond the point where it contacts the footer :

I have named the precalculated value `rightDelta`.

```
$(function() {
    var $sidebar = $("#right"), 
        $window = $(window),
        rightOffset = $sidebar.offset(),
        rightDelta = $("#footer").offset().top - $("#header").offset().top - $("#header").outerHeight() - $("#right").outerHeight(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > rightOffset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: Math.min($window.scrollTop() - rightOffset.top + topPadding, rightDelta)
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wFDYV/7/)

In fact, you can use `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` in combination to make the scroll handler a one-statement function :

```
$(function() {
    var $sidebar = $("#right"), 
        $window = $(window),
        rightOffset = $sidebar.offset(),
        rightDelta = $("#footer").offset().top - $("#header").offset().top - $("#header").outerHeight() - $("#right").outerHeight(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: Math.max(Math.min($window.scrollTop() - rightOffset.top + topPadding, rightDelta), 0)
            });
    });

});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wFDYV/8/)